# why groovy does not coerce to final classes

Tags: groovy

Recently I've run into that Groovy does not allow coercion to final classes.

```
final class Example {
    def x
}

// GroovyCastException. cannot coerce because it is final class
def a =  { x = 5 } as Example
```

Why is that? I guess it is something with the mechanism that Groovy use to coerce to classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code, but working would be:

```
@groovy.transform.ToString(includeNames=true)
final class Example {
    def x
}

def a =  [x:5] as Example

println a // Example(x:5)
```

Comment: Well still it did not help me with final classes from import.

Comment: @user1432980 no idea what that means?

Comment: It cannot create proxy for precompiled external class?

Comment: Same problem here, I have to override a public method on a precompiled final class (HttpStatus), therefore I can't add the groovy annotation to the class. I am trying to create a custom http status code for testing purposes. @user1432980 did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @user1432980 thats alright, I will work around it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Tim Yates posted, this is the problem:

```
def a =  { x = 5 } as Example
```

The reason this works:

```
def a =  [x:5] as Example
```

is because it creates a map with a value of 5 and the Groovy runtime is able to take that property of the map and assign it to the `Example` property with the same key. All that happened in that closure was a variable named X got set inside of its scope, but not a property of some object that can be transferred during the type coercion.